# How do I prevent Apache service from auto-starting on Linux?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, init

My problem is that I don't want to stop the apache daemon with the command *`./apache2 stop`* from `/etc/init.d` (I know to do this).
I don't want the apache service start automatically in `/etc/init.d` on the system startup. But I also need to keep the service in the `init.d` folder. How can I do this? Do I have to change some fields in the service script ?

Comment: Please add your distribution.

Comment: I have Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on your distro, you should be able to execute a command to disable the service on startup. Doing this it will be stopped until you manually start it. Here are some examples on different distros:

- Ubuntu/Debian: `update-rc.d -f apache2 remove`
- Gentoo: `rc-update del apache2`
- ArchLinux: `systemctl disable apache2`

Answer (score 19):

This is an old thread, but I’ll add what I've just learned to help others who come here.

For Debian, the problem with the answer given is that the change will be undone the next time there's an update to the software. From the man page for `update-rc.d`:

> A common system administration error is to delete the links with the
>   thought that this will "disable" the service, i.e., that this will
>   prevent the service from being started.  However, if all links have
>   been deleted then the next time the package is upgraded, the package's
>   postinst script will run  update-rc.d again  and  this will reinstall
>   links at their factory default locations.

I believe that it’s better to use the disable directive:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable
```

This has the advantage that the `enable` directive can reverse the change.

Comment: This was useful for fixing a *Unable to listen on required ports, port 80 is already in use* error when starting DDEV on WSL2.